# hierarchical linear regression error in python

Tags: python, linear-regression

```
    with pm.Model() as hierarchical_model:
        # Hyperpriors for group nodes
        mu_a = pm.Normal('mu_a', mu=0., sigma=100)
        sigma_a = pm.HalfNormal('sigma_a', 5.)
        mu_b = pm.Normal('mu_b', mu=0., sigma=100)
        sigma_b = pm.HalfNormal('sigma_b', 5.)
        mu_c = pm.Normal('mu_c', mu=0., sigma=100)
        sigma_c = pm.HalfNormal('sigma_c', 5.)
        mu_d = pm.Normal('mu_d', mu=0., sigma=100)
        sigma_d = pm.HalfNormal('sigma_d', 5.)
        mu_e = pm.Normal('mu_e', mu=0., sigma=100)
        sigma_e = pm.HalfNormal('sigma_e', 5.)
        mu_f = pm.Normal('mu_f', mu=0., sigma=100)
        sigma_f = pm.HalfNormal('sigma_f', 5.)

        # Intercept for each county, distributed around group mean mu_a
        # Above we just set mu and sd to a fixed value while here we
        # plug in a common group distribution for all a and b (which are
        # vectors of length n_counties).
        a = pm.Normal('a', mu=mu_a, sigma=sigma_a, shape=n_school)
        # Intercept for each county, distributed around group mean mu_a
        b = pm.Normal('b', mu=mu_b, sigma=sigma_b, shape=n_school)
        c = pm.Normal('c', mu=mu_c, sigma=sigma_c, shape=n_school)
        d = pm.Normal('d', mu=mu_d, sigma=sigma_d, shape=n_school)
        e = pm.Normal('e', mu=mu_e, sigma=sigma_e, shape=n_school)
        f = pm.Normal('f', mu=mu_f, sigma=sigma_f, shape=n_school)

        # Model error
        eps = pm.HalfCauchy('eps', 5.)

        test_score_est = a[school_idx] + b[school_idx]*df.student_ses.values+ c[school_idx]*df.student_iq.values+ d[school_idx]*df.school_avrg._ses.values+ e[school_idx]*df.school_avrg._iq.values+ f[school_idx]*df.student_gender_0.values

        # Data likelihood
        test_like = pm.Normal('test_like', mu=test_score_est,
                               sigma=eps, observed=df.test_score)
```

**I get the following error**

```
OUTPUT: IndexError: index 211 is out of bounds for size 211
```

**Hi. I get this error for hierarchical regreson. n_school = 211 why am i getting an error like this? I will be grateful if you could help me. Thanks to everyone in advance.

below I provide information on how to calculate n_school and school_idx.**

```
school_idx=df.school_id.values
n_school=len(df.school_id.unique())
OUTPUT= n_school=211
```

Answer (score 0):

Python is 0-indexed, you have 211 elements in a list like data structure, the contents will be in indices `[0,1,2,..,210]` you have a size mismatch somewhere most likely based on this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I could not fully understand.
index = 0 1 2 3 ...210
scool id = 1,1,1,2,..., 259,259,259 What exactly should I do?

Comment: what happens if you set ```n_school=len(df.school_id.unique())-1``` ? Without seeing all code its not very easy to tell.

Comment: if n_school=len(df.school_id.unique())-1 so error output ;

index 210 is out of bounds for size 210

Comment: Can you update post with full error message/stack trace?  I cannot tell which part the the error is arising from.